# Bootstrap Video Modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap for some video launching with Modal and I keep getting a weird offset video at the end of my webpage and when I click on the anchor tag it brings me to a dead link. I built a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecollins/ofuco3r2/) to even show my work. I only replaced the image and video, but I got the images from off line so its basically mimicking my code.

HTML:

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#videoModal">
     <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://iconshots.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/final1.jpg">
 </a>

<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Learn how to make this app!</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe width="500" height="281" src="http://youtu.be/GWPc6EDwv8k" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Typography
================================= */

@font-face {

    font-family:'icomoon';

    src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot');

    src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;

    font-style: normal;

}

h1 {

    font-weight: 200;

    margin-bottom: 30px;

}

h2, h3 {

    font-size: 1.25em;

    color: #5f5d60;

    margin-bottom: 16px;

    margin-top: 0;

}

p {

    color: #b3aeb5;

    line-height: 1.7;

    font-size: 1.1em;

    font-weight: 200;

}

strong {

    color: #5f5d60;

}

.navbar-text {

    font-weight: bold;

    margin-right: 0;

}

.lead {

    color: #d5c1f2;

    margin-bottom: 70px;

}

.lead:nth-of-type(2) {

    font-size: initial;

    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.main-footer {

    font-size: .95em;

}

.link-list {

    list-style-type: none;

    line-height: 1.8;

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

}

.copyright {

    opacity: .8;

    font-size: .9em;

}

/* Links
================================= */

.main-footer a {

    color: #a6afb2;

}

.link-list .heading {

    font-weight: bold;

    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

/* Layout
================================= */

hr {

    margin-bottom: 58px;

}

.ft {

    margin-bottom: 72px;

}

.ft-copy {

    padding-top: 32px;

}

.ft-copy p, .copy-offset {

    width: 88%;

}

.panel {

    background-image: url('../img/form-panel-bg.png');

    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;

    padding: 42px 0;

    margin: 80px 0 132px 0;

}

.callout {

    padding: 35px 0;

    margin-top: 64px;

    text-align: center;

    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;

    border-right: none;

    border-left: none;

}

.callout .glyphicon {

    margin-left: 10px;

}

.teacher-desc strong {

    display: block;

}

.th-copy {

    padding-top: 30px;

}

.main-footer {

    margin: 100px 0 80px 0;

}

/* Form
================================= */

.phone-txt {

    padding: 24px 12px;

    width: 90%;

}

.btn-submit {

    color: inherit;

    font-size: 1.6em;

    background: transparent;

    position: absolute;

    right: 55px;

    bottom: 3px;

}

/* Buttons
================================= */

.btn-default {

    border-width: 2px;

    border-color: inherit;

    margin-right: 10px;

    padding: 12px 22px;

}

.btn-default:hover {

    background-color: #fff;

    color: #957bba;

    border-color: #fff;

}

.btn:active {

    box-shadow: none;

}

.panel .btn-default:hover {

    background-color: #ccc;

    color: #f7f7f7;

    border-color: #ccc;

}

.btn-success {

    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #23812f;

    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);

    font-size: 1.5em;

    width: 330px;

    padding: 15px 0;

}

/* Jumbotron
================================= */

.jumbotron {

    background-image: url('../img/main-bg.png');

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-position: 200% 100%;

    padding: 200px 0 140px 0;

    margin-bottom: 70px;

}

.device {

    width: 345px;

    height: 589px;

    background: url('../img/device-hero.png') no-repeat;

}

/* Logos & Icons
================================= */

.main-logo {

    width: 124px;

    height: 34px;

    margin-top: 22px;

    text-indent: 100%;

    white-space: nowrap;

    overflow: hidden;

    background: url('../img/main-logo.png') no-repeat;

    background-size: 100%;

}

.ft-icon {

    width: 94%;

    height: 196px;

    position: relative;

    background: #8c73b0 url('../img/main-bg.png') no-repeat 270px -180px;

    background-size: 140%;

}

.ft-icon.friends {

    background-position: -500px 0px;

}

.ft-icon.cloud {

    background-position: 260px 0px;

}

.ft-icon:before {

    content:"";

    display: block;

    position: absolute;

    width: 164px;

    height: 102px;

    top: 0;

    right: 0;

    bottom: 0;

    left: 0;

    margin: auto;

    background: url('../img/feature-icons.png') no-repeat;

    background-size: 100%;

}

.friends:before {

    background-position: 0 -105px;

}

.cloud:before {

    background-position: 0 -210px;

}

[data-icon]:before {

    font-family:'icomoon';

    content: attr(data-icon);

    speak: none;

    font-weight: normal;

    font-variant: normal;

    text-transform: none;

    line-height: 1;

    margin-right: 8px;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

}

.th-logo {

    width: 155px;

    margin: -.75em 0 .95em 0;

}

/* Media Queries
================================= */

@media (max-width: 991px) {

    .jumbotron {

        padding-top: 120px;

        padding-bottom: 20px;

        background-position: 10% 10%;

    }

    .ft-copy {

        padding-top: 12px;

    }

    .ft-copy p {

        width: auto;

    }

    .device {

        margin-top: 28px;

    }

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

    .navbar {

        min-height: 60px;

    }

    .main-logo {

        width: 82px;

        margin-top: 20px;

    }

    .jumbotron {

        padding-top: 80px;

        margin-bottom: 32px;

    }

    .lead {

        margin-bottom: 40px;

    }

    .ft {

        margin-bottom: 16px;

    }

    hr {

        margin-bottom: 40px;

    }

    .btn-success {

        width: 85%;

        font-size: initial;

    }

    .callout, .link-list {

        margin-top: 32px;

    }

    .main-footer {

        margin-top: 64px;

    }

    .link-list {

        float: left;

        margin-right: 32px;

    }

}
```

Comment: JS console in the Fiddle shows an error: "Refused to display `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWPc6EDwv8k&feature=youtu.be` in a frame because it set `X-Frame-Options` to `SAMEORIGIN`."

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have included all required JS libraries such as jQuery and Bootstrap.js

I have copied your code to Codepen and it works perfectly for me (click on the gears near CSS and JS titles to see included libraries)

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/transGLUKator/pen/yyaWzr)

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#videoModal">
                <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://iconshots.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/final1.jpg">
              </a>

<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Learn how to make this app!</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KueEWP91tWc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I copied what bootstrap gave me in the dL file

Comment: I'm going to try to dL the file again see if I may have missed something at the beginning?

Comment: You need not just download the files, but include them into your html. You can include scripts with <script src="path/to/script.js"> tag and CSS files with <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css.css"> tag. You can also check Boostatrp docs and connect all required files using CDN

Comment: that's what I did, I tried it again but i got an error while it was trying to compile 
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=8385980900b3f73794cd